# Can someone help me on what is wrong in my code. I'm trying to use getkey in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use getkey of python that I downloaded from github. But somehow my code is preventing me of achieving it. The keys.UP and keys.DOWN are not functioning, but when I tried to change the "`and`" in
`if key == keys.DOWN and menu_selected + 1 != len(menu_option):` to `or` then I manage the **Down** keys to work. But the problem is, it won't let me use the **Up** keys.
Below, are the part of the code I'm talking about. Thank you in advance guys!

```
from getkey import getkey, keys
import os


def first_choice():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\nFörsta valet")
    input("Press Enter to continue....")


def second_choice():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\nAndra valet")
    input("Press Enter to continue....")


def third_choice():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\nTredje valet")
    input("Press Enter to continue....")


def end_program():
    os.system('cls')
    print("\nAvsluta programmet")
    input("Press Enter to continue....")


menu_option = ["Förstaval\t\t", "Andraval\t\t", "Tredjeval\t\t", "Avsluta\t\t"]

menu_selected = 0

while True:

os.system('cls')
print("\x1b[?25l")

if menu_selected == 0:
    print(menu_option[0] + "<--")
    print(menu_option[1])
    print(menu_option[2])
    print(menu_option[3])

elif menu_selected == 1:
    print(menu_option[0])
    print(menu_option[1] + "<--")
    print(menu_option[2])
    print(menu_option[3])

elif menu_selected == 2:
    print(menu_option[0])
    print(menu_option[1])
    print(menu_option[2] + "<--")
    print(menu_option[3])

elif menu_selected == 3:
    print(menu_option[0])
    print(menu_option[1])
    print(menu_option[2])
    print(menu_option[3] + "<--")

key = getkey()

if key == keys.DOWN and menu_selected + 1 != len(menu_option):
    menu_selected += 1
elif key == keys.UP and not (menu_selected == 0):
    menu_selected -= 1
elif key == keys.ENTER:
    if menu_selected == 0:
        first_choice()
    elif menu_selected == 1:
        second_choice()
    elif menu_selected == 2:
        third_choice()
    elif menu_selected == 3:
        end_program()
        break
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Is your while loop indented correctly in the actual code? Maybe it is not iterating through the loop at all. It would make sense that it would only work for a single keypress if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for the response. And yes, while loop is indented correctly. I edited my post and included the whole thing that belongs to it.